# Prove that $\forall n\ge 1$, there are $n$ successive, non-prime,natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\forall n\ge 1$, there are $n$ successive, non-prime,natural numbers.

How can I turn to such a question? I have never dealt with such before. I started to course this week. I would really appreciate it if you led me or assisted me.

Answer (score 5):

$(n+1)!
+2,(n+1)!+3,(n+1)!+4, \dots , (n+1)!+n+1$

The number $(n+1)!+i$ is a multiple of $i$ since $i$ divides both $i$ and $(n+1)!$

Comment: What is the inductive way to show that? 
I am a bit confused

Comment: You don't have to use induction. If you want, you can formulate this proof as mathematical induction in which the induction hypothesis is never used. But why would you do that?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to look at a sequence which is "very divisible", in the sense that we know in advance that all the numbers won't be prime. The following is probably the easiest:

$(n+1)!+2, ... ,(n+1)!+(n+1)$